# How to reference all the cell values in in a column to perform a comparison between the values?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use an `if` function that checks if there are values in a column that are similar and if so perform an action. The function I am using is

```
=IF(A2=A3 & C2<>C3, B2-B3)
```

The values I am trying to compare are as follows:
[image: Image of excel file im working on]

I want the function to do this: if any two values of Column A are similar (ID number) and appear on the same day, and the status of these two similar values is different (IN and OUT), then it should deduct the time difference between the date and time of the values that satisfy the three conditions.

The `if` function I used above, when I extend it downwards it compares then in order instead of comparing all the values. For example it check A2 and A3 for the first row then A3 and A4 for the second and then A4 and A5 for the third.

Another issue is that the if function only works on two columns instead of three. I can't write this:

```
=IF(A10=A11 & C10<>C11 & B10=B11, B10-B11).
```

It'll display `false`.

Comment: This sounds like you need some database functionality, and towards that end, you might want to look into pivot tables or maybe even using Access.

Comment: If an ID 1001 then it has to match with another ID that is 1001

Answer (score 0):

Use Index/match to find date and time of the next matching order with same date and different status in D2

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B$10,MATCH(1,INDEX((A2:A$10=A2)*(INT(B2:B$10)=INT(B2))*(C2:C$10<>C2),0),0)),"")
```

Then just find the difference in times in E2

```
=IF(D2="","",ABS(B2-D2))
```

[image]